# How to pass canvas reference to class

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a simple game and I have a class that I call GameLoop and inside the run() method the code is passing the reference of the canvas to a method that draws a circle. This code is just some testcode.

My question is how do I pass the reference of the canvas if I want to create several sprite objects(classes) with a circle and put them in a list when the game starts? I have done this before, but then I used bitmap in each sprite object and just passed a reference of the image, but in this case I'm not sure how I would do since the canvas is inside the run() method, and I want to create my sprite objects in a method like initializeGameObjects() once in the beginning. I hope my question isn't unclear!? Preciate some help! Thanks!

```
// Game loop ---------------------------------------
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    while (gameRunning) {
        if (!surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;

    canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

    // Call method to draw objects on screen
    drawObjects(canvas);

    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}
// End game loop ---------------------------------------

// Method that draw everything on canvas
private void drawObjects(Canvas canvas) {

    // Test
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    // Clear screen with black color
    canvas.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);

    // Draw a circle
    canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 100, paint);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would implement Runnable and construct a Thread. This way you can have a "setup" method which ultimately calls a "start" method. The "start" method would draw to the canvas before starting the thread.

This is actually better practice for this kind of stuff. You may want to init stuff before starting a thread.

```
public class Game implements Runnable {
    private Thread thisThread = new Thread(this);
    private boolean gameRunning = false;

    public void startGame() {
       gameRunning = true;
       //Draw to canvas
       thisThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(gameRunning) {
        //Draw other objects
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you haven't already, you should consider double buffering.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what is double buffering? Sorry, I'm new to this kind of programming! And in your code, how do I handle and get the canvas reference?

Comment: Its up to you how you get the canvas reference, you could pass it in with the Game constructor and store it as an instance field or have a static reference to it in some object somewhere.

Double buffering is basically drawing an image off the screen before displaying it on the screen. Effectively you have an image that is currently displayed on the screen and an image that is being drawn off the screen. Once drawn, the off screen image is swapped with the one on screen. Take a look at BufferedImage and the createGraphics method.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Double buffering, isn't that what is happening inside the run() method!? Anyway it's working now. I managed to pass the canvas in another way, almost like I have done before. Finally I can continue with my project.

Answer (score 1):

Define an interface:

```
public interface Renderable{
    public void renderToCanvas(Canvas c);
}
```

Define a List of `Renderables`:

```
private List<Renderable> sprites = new ArrayList<Renderable>();
```

create methods to add/remove sprites, make sure they are synchronized:

```
public synchronized void addSprite(Renderable r){
  sprites.add(r);
}

public synchronized void removeSprite(Renderable r){
  sprites.remove(r);
}
```

This is drawing method, also synchronized, so you don't end up drawing and modifying sprite list at same time. This is either called in a loop by other thread, or a view's `onDraw()` method:

```
public synchronized void draw(Canvas c){
  // lock canvas if needed

  // common drawing code

  for(Renderable r :sprites){
    r.renderToCanvas(c);
  }

  // release canvas if locked
}
```

Now, you are free to define any type of sprite, Circle, Square or whatever,

```
public class Circle implements Renderable{
  private Paint mPaint;
  private float mRadius;

  public Circle(Paint p, float r){
    mPaint = p;
    mRadius = r;
  }

  @Override
  public void renderToCanvas(Canvas c){
    c.drawCircle(100, 100, mRadius, mPaint);
  }
}
```

and add it to sprite list:

```
addSprite(new Circle(new Paint(),20f));
```

**Note:** I used `synchronized` for simplicity, but there are better alternatives to it like atomic flags.These are required only if you want to add/remove sprites while game loop is running. If you setup all sprites *before* starting game loop, this is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the code! This looks very interesting, but a little bit hard to understand at once.